# How to use and check the performance improvement by HipHop for PHP?

Tags: php, hiphop

I am impressed by the discussions around HipHop PHP from Facebook, also want to try it once. I found many articles saying how HipHop is improving performance and I found installation steps as well. But no where I found the steps/guide to use this HipHop and check the performance improvement.

I guess many people already used the HipHop, so please let me know the exact steps to use the HipHop and check the performance improvement. If you know there are already some blogs or something to specify the corresponding flow then at least please point me to those resources.

**FYI:** I have already installed the HipHop in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS by following the instructions from the [wiki page](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04), but don't know to use that. I am using CodeIgniter framework in my project.

Comment: Hi All, seems none of our SO users have used the HipHop for PHP so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach (for a web application) would be to run [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html), a pretty simple benchmarking tool.

It will not take other resources like images or scripts into account, but only response time of the page itself, so you should get a decent idea about what the load times were before and after. To test concurrenct request handling, it has options for parallel requests.

Basic usage is something like

```
ab -n2000 -c5 http://www.example.com
```

Where n is the amoutn of requests and c is the concurrency level

Comment: Thanks Vondra, do you have any idea about the HipHop PHP? If so please let me know how to use that first.

Comment: Hey Vondra, first I need to know the steps to use this HipHop PHP, then only I can try your answer to check the performance improvement, so please help me out to use the HipHop if you know.

Comment: You've read this page? https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop

Comment: Hi Vondra, some how I missed this useful wiki page, thanks for pointing me to this resource, I am facing some error while trying to run HipHop now, just posted a new question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562142/error-while-trying-to-run-the-hiphop-in-mode-2compiling-hiphop-in-a-temporary), can you please help me to solve that issues also...

Comment: The wiki page no longer exists is there another resource?