# Error while trying to run the HipHop in "Mode 2(Compiling HipHop in a temporary directory and running the compiled program from the command line)"

Tags: php, hiphop

I have installed the HipHop and all the dependencies in my VM(Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), no issues faced while setting up the environment. But I am not able to run the HipHop in Mode 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 as specified in the wiki document *https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop*.

I am trying to run the HipHop in **Mode 2** then facing some error with a message of "sudo: /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8/program: command not found", can you please help me to fix this issue and start using the HipHop in a correct direction.

Just posting my terminal response for your reference:

***siva@siva-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/dev/hiphop-php$*** $HPHP_HOME/src/hphp/hphp /var/www/test.php k 1 --log=3
running hphp...
creating temporary directory /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8 ...
parsing inputs...
parsing inputs took 0'00" (3 ms) wall time
pre-optimizing...
pre-optimizing took 0'00" (0 ms) wall time
analyze includes...
analyze includes took 0'00" (0 ms) wall time
inferring types...
inferring types took 0'00" (0 ms) wall time
post-optimizing...
post-optimizing took 0'00" (1 ms) wall time
creating binary HHBC files...
creating binary HHBC files took 0'00" (6 ms) wall time
running executable /home/siva/dev/hiphop-php/src/hhvm/hhvm -vRepo.Authoritative=true -vRepo.Commit=false -vRepo.Local.Mode=r -vRepo.Local.Path=/tmp/hphp_DF8jr8/hhvm.hhbc --file /var/www/test.php...
This is my first php programm...all files saved in /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8 ...
running hphp took 0'00" (443 ms) wall time
***siva@siva-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/dev/hiphop-php$*** /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8/program
bash: /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8/program: No such file or directory
***siva@siva-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/dev/hiphop-php$*** sudo /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8/program
sudo: /tmp/hphp_DF8jr8/program: command not found

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to to add --keep-tempdir option. See docs on your link more carefully.